# String input with spaces in 2D array

Tags: java, string

I want to take string inputs in java which is separated by spaces in a 2D array and display all the items in a separate line.

e.g:
**input:**

> item1 3 5
>   item2 7 4

**output:**

> item1
>   3
>   5
>   item2
>   7
>   4

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = sc.nextInt();
int b = sc.nextInt();
String array_of_items[][] = new String[a][b];
for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
{ 
  String str = sc.nextLine(); 
  String[] lineVector = str.split(" ");
  for(int j=0;j<b;j++)
  {
    array_of_items[i][j] = lineVector[j];
  }
}

for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j<b;j++)
  {
    System.out.println(array_of_items[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Your "input" and "output" are the same in the example, is it what you intended to write?

Comment: You get `lineVector` by splitting a string. It seems to me that there may be not enough elements in it, which may be causing the out of bounds exception. You should check the length of `lineVector` before accessing it's elements (or catch the exception somewhere).

Comment: Yes I want the same elements in output. Thanks... It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

The first `String str = sc.nextLine();` reads the new line from `int b = sc.nextInt();` so your `lineVector` is empty => `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you try to access `lineVector[j]`. The fix is to consume that line by adding a `sc.nextLine();` after `int b = sc.nextInt();`.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = sc.nextInt();
int b = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
String array_of_items[][] = new String[a][b];
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    String[] lineVector = str.split(" ");
    for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
        array_of_items[i][j] = lineVector[j];
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
        System.out.println(array_of_items[i][j]);
    }
}
```

**Input**

```
2
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

**Output**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```